# Silverlight - enabled Service : Error 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: wcf, silverlight, service

**Important Update : Today i tried to change the binding type from customBinding to basicHttpBinding, which directly worked. This enabled me to use maxBufferSize etc. so please regard my problem as answered. Here is my code  (web.config) :**

```
 <bindings>
    <!--<customBinding>
      <binding name="WCFLogServiceProvider.WCFLogService.customBinding0">
      <binaryMessageEncoding />
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding> //Old binding configuration. This configuration will be generated when you start with a Silverlight enabled service. -->
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WCFLogServiceProvider.WCFLogService.customBinding0" maxBufferPoolSize="1500000"
         maxReceivedMessageSize="1500000"
         maxBufferSize="1500000">
      <readerQuotas
            maxArrayLength="656000"
            maxBytesPerRead="656000"
            maxDepth="32"
            maxNameTableCharCount="656000"
            maxStringContentLength="656000"
        />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

**For any future Reader who works with a Silverlight - enabled service, please note :
Try to change the binding type from customBinding to basicHttpBinding. Changes are high, that this will work without any further changes. Alternative solutions are still welcome, though.**

Hello People at StackOverflow,

i have the following issue:

i want to upload entries from log files automatically to a database. The application itself is doing it's job fine, but when passing the generic list containing the log entries to the WCF Service at the other end, i get the error 413.

I already checked, whether i could simply set the maxBufferSize property as described in many answers, but as i am using a Silverlight - enabled Service (because the application using it is cross platform), i don't have a basicHttpBinding, but a customBinding. I normally (try to) upload a list of at least some hundred log entries represented as objects (not string)

Here's my web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="300"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="WCFLogServiceProvider.WCFLogService.customBinding0">
          <binaryMessageEncoding />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFLogServiceProvider.WCFLogService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="WCFLogServiceProvider.WCFLogService.customBinding0"
      contract="WCFLogServiceProvider.WCFLogService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- Legen Sie die Werte unten vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Metadateninformationen zu vermeiden. -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- Damit in Fehlern Ausnahmedetails zum Debuggen angezeigt werden, legen Sie den Wert unten auf "true" fest. Legen Sie ihn vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Ausnahmeinformationen zu vermeiden. -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<!--
    Um das Stammverzeichnis der Webanwendung beim Debuggen auszuwählen, legen Sie den Wert unten auf "true" fest.
    Legen Sie ihn vor der Bereitstellung auf "false" fest, um die Veröffentlichung von Informationen über den Webanwendungsordner zu vermeiden.
  -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: @mathk Can you please show me, what you exactly edited ?

Comment: Click the link above my name.

Comment: I dont think it is related to your configuration